# How to simultaneously extract contourvalues and contourline?

Tags: plotting, labeling

Given a contour plot,

```
plt=ContourPlot[Sin[x y],{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1}]
```

I can extract the values of the contour lines using,

```
Cases[Normal@plot, Line[pts_, ___] :> pts, Infinity]
```

and the contour values using,

```
Cases[FullForm[plot], Tooltip[{__}, b_] :> b, Infinity]}
```

However, I would like to get the contour value corresponding to each contour line (e.g. in the form {contour value, line}). If the contours are connected then this is easy since each line is in one-to-one relationship to the contour value and you can just use the ordering. However, if the contours are disconnected this is no longer the case. How would I go about finding this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like this might work. I think that the `Line`s are grouped with their values in `Graphics`, so that

```
list = Cases[Normal@plt, Tooltip[{__, a__Line}, b_] :> {a, b}, Infinity]
```

will do the trick. This will return a list where the last element is the value, and the previous elements are the `Line`s.

To check, note that

```
Framed@Graphics[{Most@#, Text[ToString[Last@#], {0, 0}]}] & /@ list // GraphicsRow
```

yields

[image]

To get just the list of coordinates rather than the `Line`s, do

```
Cases[Normal@plt, Tooltip[{__, a__Line}, b_] :> {Sequence @@ First /@ {a}, b}, Infinity]
```