# How to extract contour values from ContourPlot3D?

Tags: plotting

From this interesting link [How to simultaneously extract contourvalues and contourline?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89905/how-to-simultaneously-extract-contourvalues-and-contourline)
I've learnd how to extract the contourvalues from a `ContourPlot`-graphicsobject.

Is it possible to extend this approach to `ContourPlot3D`?

For example

```
plt = ContourPlot3D[Sqrt[4/(Pi)^2] Sin[1 x] Sin[2 y] Sin[2 z] , {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0,Pi}, {z, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> None, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

shows some different contours whose value I would like to know.

I tried

```
poly = Cases[plt, GraphicsGroup[p_] -> p, Infinity]
```

which gives three groups of polygons (probably the contours I'm looking for), but doesn't show a contourvalue!

No idea how to proceed!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
PlotLegends -> Automatic
```

```
plt = ContourPlot3D[
  Sqrt[4/(Pi)^2] Sin[1 x] Sin[2 y] Sin[2 z], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, 
   Pi}, {z, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> None, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
Cases[plt, SwatchLegend[a__] :> a, Infinity][[2]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, very good idea. But `Cases `misses the contourvalue `0`!

Comment: That's it, thank you very much. Didn't know `SwatchLegend`